# Which SQL is faster? Select and then Update VS. Update with inner select

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, triggers

I am using an Oracle Database. See these 2 examples (doing exactly the same):

1.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LAST_CHANGE_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT
    ON TABLE_X_HAVING_ITEM_ID
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    style_id NUMBER(18);

BEGIN      
    -- 1. get style_id
    SELECT
        ITEM.STYLE_ID
    INTO
        style_id
    FROM
        ITEM
    WHERE
        ITEM.ITEM_ID = :NEW.ITEM_ID;

    -- 2. set last_modified
    UPDATE
        STYLE
    SET
        STYLE.LAST_MODIFIED = SYSDATE
    WHERE
        STYLE.STYLE_ID = style_id;
END;
/
```

2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LAST_CHANGE_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT
    ON TABLE_X_HAVING_ITEM_ID
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    UPDATE
        STYLE
    SET
        STYLE.LAST_MODIFIED = SYSDATE
    WHERE
        STYLE.STYLE_ID = (
            SELECT
                ITEM.STYLE_ID
            FROM
                ITEM
            WHERE
                ITEM.ITEM_ID = :NEW.ITEM_ID
        );
END;
/
```

I heard that the 2. one would be faster. I think the 1. one is easier to understand though (more straight forward).
Can you explain/proof that 2. is faster? If you can do so, is this only the case for oracle?

Comment: Not performance relevant, but: the assignment `item_id := :NEW.ITEM_ID;` is completely useless. You can use `:NEW.ITEM_ID` directly in your SQL statements.

Comment: In my code I have a IF-ELSE block that assigns the item_id. I left it away for stackoverflow, but I forgot to remove the assignment :)

Comment: Just double-checking...  `TABLE_X_HAVING_ITEM_ID` is different from both `item` and `style`, right?  It seems odd that adding a row to a third table would cause the `last_modified` of the `style` table to be set-- normally you'd expect that to happen only when something changed in the `style` table itself.

Comment: hey Justin, maybe I should not have removed the real name from TABLE_X_HAVING_ITEM_ID. Its name is ITEMOPTION, so it really belongs to a style!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second should be faster, because you don't have two round trips to the database.

It also allows multiple rows to be updated at the same time, in case there are multiple matches.

That said, I don't see why this trigger is necessary.  You can just look up the style when querying the data.  Storing redundant data -- particularly to a reference table -- seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I think that the trigger is nice, because the STYLE.LAST_MODIFIED has to be updated to the current date, whenever a related table is changed. This is a request from the product owner. This trigger(s) fulfill this request in a good way, don't they?

Comment: This is PL/SQL code, so what do you mean by "two round trips to the database"?  Do you mean context switches?  You're probably right, but I'm guessing that in practice it's more of a wash.  I think I'd prefer the 2nd more for the read-consistency than any performance difference.  Also... wouldn't both approaches allow for multiple rows to be updated?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak . . . Each query needs to be separately compiled and the results need to processed to pass back to the PL/SQL code.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak it will not update multiple rows. This is ensured by constraints that are not shown here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your help! I understand it like that, but still I would like to dig deeper into this. Can I see the implementation somewhere or debug into it?